# trespassing to personal property?

Tags: criminal-law, business, property, trespass, employer

Let say I went into a store and bought something. When I was walking out an employee or the manager stop me and ask to look inside my bag because they assume I was stealing. Before, I could even respond because I was surprised, they grab my bag and look inside with out my consent. Could I be able to sue them for trespassing ( personal property)?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: I don't think that's a dupe (though it is related). The linked question is about whether you may refuse if the shop asks you to search the bag. This is about whether you can sue them if they look without asking.

Comment: Absolutely duplicate. The top answer there is the exact answer to this question: *"If they attempt to force you to surrender your bags for search by physical force or by intimidation, you may be entitled to bring a claim for the tort of assault and/or battery. You need only prove that these occurred, without actual loss or damage."*

Comment: Look up "Shopkeeper's Privilege" and "Citizen's Arrest" laws in your state (assuming United States.  It's also in Common Law nations).  These can give you an idea of what your state allows.